# WebAuthn does not guarantee public-key integrity other than trough attestation?

Tags: authentication, integrity, csr, public-key, webauthn

I've been reading about WebAuthn and try to write some code to exercise.

One thing I noticed is that the spec doesn't seem to provide any way to verify the correctness of the public-key being `create()`'d other than through attestation. And by TOFU paradigm mentioned in [MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Authentication_API/Attestation_and_Assertion), it's not to be verified in the first place.

However, with PKIX CSR, the public-key in the cert request is signed by its corresponding private key, which provide a basic level of verification.

So, what are the pro's and con's of public-key verification signatures? Why WebAuthn choose this over that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of further reading, I found these:

The '[self](https://w3c.github.io/webauthn/#self-attestation)' attestation type is WebAuthn's equivalent of verifying a public key with itself. This attestation type is currently only supported by '[packed](https://w3c.github.io/webauthn/#sctn-packed-attestation)' statement format.

The danger of not verifying the public key is shortly mentioned in Chapter 7 where recommended rely party behavior is specified. Specifically, the note following [step 26 of "Registering a New Credential](https://w3c.github.io/webauthn/#sctn-registering-a-new-credential) - it's discussed in the rationale note explaining why a duplicated public key credential should be rejected (because it's not integrity protected unless attestation type is 'self')

As for the pro's and con's of integrity protecting the public key - THERE IS NO CON:)

Comment: are we now referring to chapters of a unknown source?

not very helpful...

Comment: @LvB, I assumed readers would automatically refer to the [WebAuthn draft from W3C](https://w3c.github.io/webauthn). Added link to make it clearer.

Comment: while that was the first thing that popped to mind for me... I know it wouldn't for everyone. in any case. in the future it might not be as obvious anymore. so thank you for adding the links.